# Trouble aligning button with input

Tags: html, css

I've tried to align the button submit and the search input but I doesn't work and I don't get to understand why.
I have this styling code:

```
input[type=search] 
    border: none
    cursor: text
    padding: 0
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf
.search-main input, .search-main button
    height: 30px
    display: inline-block

.search-main button 
    background: #55e0a8
    border: none
    width: 18%
    margin-left: -7px
    display:inline-block

.search-main input
    width: 80%
```

and this html:

```
<form method="get" class="search-main">
    <input name="q" type="search">
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

and here's what I get:

[image]
[Here's the online version](http://aurelieremia.be/bruxelles-proprete-final/)

So, pretty silly question, but since I've been trying for more than 40+ minutes, thought I would try to post it here. I've been playing with firebug, padding, margins, and I don't get where the problem comes from.

Comment: We have `{` and `;` in CSS :)

Comment: 6   </head>
   7 This tag or content is not allowed here. One of the following was expected: <body> 
     E612 This tag or content is not allowed here:
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/screen.css">
   8   <body>

Comment: @Mr.Alien Oh, yes, I just copy/pasted it from my .sass file :)

Answer (score 4):

You can try -

```
.search-main > button {
float: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh. So simple, aha, thank you ! I don't get why the "inline-block" didn't get the job done though.

Comment: Naemy, display: inline-block did work but you forgot to put vertical-align: top; and you had way to much negative margins. Once i put vertical-align: top on your button and input they aligned, and reduced your margin-left: -4 it looks better than the float. No offense swapnesh, my beef with floats is how unpredictable they can be and how much more coding has to be done to make them work.

Answer (score 2):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to your `inline-block` elements:

```
.search-main input, .search-main button {
    height: 29px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: i think just a vertical-align:middle to the <button> would fix.

Answer (score 1):

Problems arise when you use `height` on inline elements.

You can simply remove the `height` and replace with `padding` on both elements :

```
.search-main input, .search-main button {
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.search-main button {
  background: #55e0a8
  border: none
  width: 18%
  margin-left: -7px
  display:inline-block
  padding: 11px 0; // +1px for border on the input
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was easy, I hope the following code suffices what you needed.

```
.search-main button {
                    background: #55e0a8;
                    border: none;
                    width: 18%;
                    margin-left: -7px;
                    display: inline-block;    //additional code
                    float: left;              //additional code  
                    vertical-align: middle;   //additional code
                    height: 32px;             //additional code 
                    }
```

and this for the input:

```
<input name="q" type="search" style=" display: inline-block;float: left;">
```

Comment: Thank you ! I don't get why, with the same height, the two elements don't have the same height though.

Comment: @Naemy, your code is rendering with a width of `32px` for the input and `30px` for the button somehow. Try this code:
     <input name="q" type="search" style="
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
">

<button type="submit" style="
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    height: 32px;
"></button>